# getting image file from php image resoure

Tags: php, image, gd

When i use `imagecopyresized()` function on php it returns as image resource, and what i want is to get the image data from this image resource.may be like a file location in a string or an array containg several data of the file like the one you get in the $_FILES[] global array. thanks

```
$source = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($source);
echo BR.$height."   ".$width;
$desired_height = 28;
$scale = $width/$height;
$new_width = $desired_height * $scale;
$new_height = $desired_height; 
$original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
$resized_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
if(imagecopyresized($resized_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height)){
    echo BR."image resized".BR;
}
```

i want to store the location of `$resized_image` in to database but i cant seem to access the file location from this variable.

Answer (score 0):

This will put your image contents to the $buffer variable as a jpeg.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im, null, 90);
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

You can then save it with `file_put_contents` to a desired path and save the path to the database.

See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Alternatively, you could use a 3rd party library with a nicer API, such as [Nette\Utils\Image](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/images) or [Intervention\Image](http://image.intervention.io/).

Answer (score 0):

`imagecreatetruecolor` creates an image resource in memory and returns its identifier. It does not create any physical file with the image in it.

Use `imagejpeg` like:

`imagejpeg($resized_image, '/path/to/save/img.jpg')`

It will create and save an image file to disk. And then you can store that path in database.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

Answer (score 0):

$resized_image is not associated with afile. 
You need to use imagejpeg, imagepng, .. methods to save resources to a file.

```
imagejpeg($resized_image, 'path/file.jpg');
```